# Form Tag Helper not generate correct HTML (areas ?)

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

Regarding official information to ASP.NET Core 1.1.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms

Form tag helper should generate some valid mvc HTML.

But by some reason my view that is located in some area never do it
I see output HTML like

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
```

My _ViewImports.cshtml is shared (global - 1 file no in area):

```
   @using ATA
    @using ATA
    @using ATA.Security.Models.AccountViewModels
    @using ATA.Security.Models.ManageViewModels
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
    @addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
    @addTagHelper "*, ATA.Security"
```

" - were added by me but it is no difference in html output results , if i revet it back

what could be an issue for such case ?

Comment: Please don't use ASP.NET Core and .NET Core interchangeably!!! ASP.NET Core is an Rest Api/MVC webstack, .NET Core is a runtime. Your question is in anyway related to the runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue when push _ViewImports.cshtml to View folder.
Seems like share _ViewImports.cshtml file is not supported

Comment: If you reorganize your Views into a Feature based folder structure don't forget to do this.